# How to call a same component multiple times with different input and display it in same page

Tags: angular, angular6, components, multiple-instances

I have a parent component with few scripts. I have a child component which will display details about the script . I'm passing script name as input to my child component every time. I get details from server and display it in child.html page.

Here, When I click a script every time, the old script details gets replaced with the new script(clicked script) details. I don't want my old script details to go away when I click on the new one

I'm new to angular. Could someone help me with this. Basically I want to load the same component multiple times for different inputs and display all together.Below is just a code example of what I'm trying to achieve..

## parent.html

```
parent.html

<li> script1 <li>
<li> script2 <li>
<input type=button (onclick)=getDetails(script)>
<app-script-details 
    *ngIf="showChild"
    [job]="currentScript">
</app-Script-details>
```

-- Calling Child component with clicked script as input

### parent component.ts

```
getDetails(script){
   this.showChild=true
   this.currentScript=script  // Clicked script
}
```

### Child.html

```
<h1>Script A - Details </h1>
```

### child component.html

```
 @Input() script

// Here I make a call to the server and get the details from server and display in child.html
```

Here, If I click Script A first, it will show Script A Details and then if I click script B, Script A details will be replaced with Script B details.

I want to show both details at the same time.. Script A and while it is loading(waiting from response from server) if I click Script B,It should start loading and Both the script details should come whenever available.

Comment: provide minimal code to understand your requirement properly, so that helps us to solve your issue.

Comment: @ganesh045 : Added basic code example of what I'm trying to do.. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ngFor` to iterate over an array of clicked scripts and display the child component.

For example, create an array in your parent component to store the clicked scripts.

```
clickedScripts = [
    {id: 1, name: 'script A'},
    {id: 2, name: 'script B'},
    {id: 3, name: 'script C'},
]
```

Keep pushing any new clicked script object into this array.
Then in your template use the child component to display them.

```
<div>
    <child-component *ngFor="let script of clickedScripts" [scriptName]="script.name">
</div>
```

Also, please have a look at `trackBy` function in the angular documentation. It will help with performance and not refresh the entire rendered template every time you push a new element into the array.

Comment: Added a code example of what I'm trying to do.. Please have a look and advise. Thanks..

Comment: Have implemented a working example @ https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-parent-child. Note: Avoid making service calls from child components. Have a look at Presentation vs Container components concept about UI development with Angular, React, Vue etc.